# Plugins menu not on dashboard

Tags: plugins, google-analytics

I'm new to WP and am using it through my university's account. As far as I can tell, it should be a .org site (when I hover over the WP symbol in the top left corner wordpress.org is one of the options). I need to be able to track the number of visits to the site and other similar usage, and was hoping to install the Google Analytics plugin. However there is no plugin option in the dashboard - as in, the word "plugin" does not exist on the left hand menu that goes down the left hand side of the page.

I assume my university has done something weird to have this happen, but I've absolutely no idea what it could be, or how I might get access to visitation data. Or how to install any plugins at all.

I'm not sold on Google Analytics, I've never used that before either so I just want something that works. If you have any suggestions on either how to get it to work or other options I could try, I would be very grateful.

Cheers.

Comment: is this your account is administrator or different role.

Comment: @Teresa you might not have permissions to install plugins. You might not be an admin.

Comment: What is your main concern here? Do you just want to add google analytics or you are concerned about not finding plugin option in backend? if its just about analytics you can do it manually without using a plugin, if you have access to the file system. Go through this https://www.wpbeginner.com/beginners-guide/how-to-install-google-analytics-in-wordpress/

Comment: Many Universities run a MultiSite - meaning only administrators of the main site can install plugins; those logging into individual sites cannot. Check with whoever set up your account and they should be able to assist.